# WP7.1 send email with attachment

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send email with an attachment using Windows Phone 7 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011267/how-to-send-email-with-an-attachment-using-windows-phone-7-api)

Is it possible with WP7 (Mango 7.1) to send email with attachments?
I've seen some posts about using a webservice to send the email, but I was hoping that this is no longer needed in 7.1

Would it be possilbe to serialize my attachment and put it in as the body of the message?  The attachment I want to send is around 5MB, would the Body be able to hold that much data ?

If I did go with the WebService route is there any public webservices that will do this? Its a free app so standing up my own server isnt going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to send attachments via the EmailComposeTask in Mango. The only option is to do what you read and use a web service.

You can vote for the feature [here](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1884923-support-attachments-in-emailcomposetask?ref=title).

Comment: is it possible to create a custom screen to send emails using an external SMTP server then?

Comment: Yes, if you use your own SMTP server and custom web services, you can send emails with attachments.