# Email with attachment in WP 7, 8 … 100?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send email with an attachment using Windows Phone 7 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011267/how-to-send-email-with-an-attachment-using-windows-phone-7-api)

Is there any chance (now or in future) to send an Email
 in WP ? “EmailComposeTask” doesn’t support this. Did anyone know some other
 way? Maybe Open Source Project, or tool? For any suggestion thanks in advance.

Regards, Emil